# How to pass/mock the admin_required decorator in gae?

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, mocking, flask-restful

```
class Generator(Resource):

    @admin_required
    def get(self):
       pass
```

If I add the @admin_required decorator on my view, the unit test start failing, with the message:

> RuntimeError: working outside of request context

Is there a way to mock it or bypass it for unit tests?

Here is the decorator:

```
def admin_required(func):
    """Requires App Engine admin credentials"""
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        if users.get_current_user():
            if not users.is_current_user_admin():
                abort(401)  # Unauthorized
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return redirect(users.create_login_url(request.url))
    return decorated_view
```

Comment: It looks like you can just patch `users.is_current_user_admin` (and possibly `users.get_current_user`)

Comment: I work around the @login_required annotation in unit tests by setting the request.user -- perhaps you could do a similar thing by setting request.user to be an admin user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just patch the users module:

```
from google.appengine.api import users

# ...

@mock.patch.object(users, 'get_current_user')
@mock.patch.object(users, 'is_current_user_admin', return_value=True)
def test_handler(mock_get_current_user, mock_is_current_user_admin):
    invoke_your_handler()
    # make assertions, etc.
```

If you want to go deeper, you could use that GAE testbed ... Unfortunately, the documentation here seems to be pretty poor and tricky to get right... Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159396/how-do-you-mock-the-user-service-in-app-engine), it looks like you need to create a testbed instance and then set the environment:

```
from google.appengine.ext import testbed

testbed = testbed.TestBed()
testbed.activate()
testbed.init_user_stub()
# Sets environment variables...
testbed.setup_env(
    user_email='hello@gmail.com',
    user_id='123456',
    user_is_admin='1',  # '1' is an admin, '0' is a non-admin.
    overwrite=True,
)
```

Now continue your test as usual.  If you are using `unittest` for testing, you'd probably want to pack all of that fun stuff into your `setUp` method.

Also note, in order to avoid polluting your environment, you'll want to call `testbed.deactivate()` at the end of the test.

Comment: The mocking works great. Many thanks. The testbed is a better idea in this case, as I don't have to change each related unittest. It seems there is no `testbed.set_env()` but there is `testbed.setup_env()`, however it doesn't work and throws the same error message. Granted I used `hello@gmail.com` as email as well, which I believe should be fine to do.

Comment: Oops, sorry `setup_env` :-)... Without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to guess at what the problem is... Did you read through the answer I linked about using testbed?

Comment: Right. +1 The solution was to add `overwrite=True` to the `setup_env` otherwise it had no effect. On another note, when you mentioned "pack all that fun stuff into your `setUp`", I remembered I tried this and failed to achieve it. You seem to know this very well, please have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223321/how-to-move-the-mock-patch-to-the-setup

Comment: Updated this answer with `overwrite=True` and answered the other question as well.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Oh, and here the packing stuff into setUp is easier... You just add a testbed instance to the TestCase (`self.testbed = testbed.TestBed()`) in `setUp`.  Then finish setting it up as we did above.  Then make sure that `self.testbed.deactivate` is called after the tests by passing it to `addCleanup` or putting it in `tearDown`.