# Good approach to mocking objects in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to understand Python Mock to better unit test my code.  I haven't done much unit testing in the past, but I want to emphasize it moving forward.  The "with mock.patch('something') as mock:" syntax seems really handy for mocking objects that my code is utilizing.  This has been especially convenient for mimicking database or API calls.

However, I'm noticing as the number of tests I write go up, so does the duplication in my tests.  If I have multiple classes used within my class (MyClass below) that need to be mocked, I need to mock them for multiple tests even if they aren't being directly used for a particular test.  For example:

```
with context("my test"):
  with it('responds true'):
    with mock.patch('lib.mymodule.ClassA') as MockClassA:
      with mock.patch('lib.mymodule.ClassB') as MockClassB:
        with mock.patch('lib.mymodule.ClassC') as MockClassC:
          MockClassA.return_value = "bogus result"
          f = MyClass("host", "user", "password")
          self.assertEqual(f, "bogus result")
```

In this case, MockClassA, B, and C might talk to a database or make an API call, which I don't actually want to do during testing.  But since my class is using each, I need to mock all of them for all tests.  Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: fixed my code to reflect that I'm using Mamba for unit testing.  I apologize for not mentioning that initially.

Comment: Should that be `class TestHostRecordCreation(unittest.TestCase):`?

Comment: Your question seems similar to the question asked at http://stackoverflow.com/q/28223321/748858 ... In that answer I show how to move patches into the test cases' `setUp` method, or to use it as a class decorator.  Have a look there and see if it helps you with your problem here.

Comment: I apologize, I was typing that freehand.  I'm actually using Mamba, not unittest.

Comment: I don't know `mamba`, but a quick look at the github site seems like it should work very similar ... Move my `setUp` code into the `with before.each` block and my `tearDown` code into `with after.each` and you're pretty much all set... make some adjustments (e.g. you're not gonna call the super class methods), but the idea should be the same...

Comment: The "with" context managers in mamba were nice at first, but I can't decorate them with patch.  So I tried using patch.start() / patch.stop(), but my tests are starting to look pretty ugly.  I think I'm going to switch over to unittest next time.  Thanks for your link, it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not just a case if [`patch` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) starts with

> patch() acts as a function decorator, class decorator ....

Use patch as decorator is one of the best way to improve readability and simplicity. Your case become

```
def TestHostRecordCreation(self):
    @mock.patch('lib.mymodule.ClassC')
    @mock.patch('lib.mymodule.ClassB')
    @mock.patch('lib.mymodule.ClassA')
    def test_create_record(self, MockClassA, MockClassB, MockClassC):
        f = MyClass("host", "user", "password")
        self.assertEqual(f, "bogus result")
```

Moreover if you want to make the same patches for all test cases you can decorate the class instead of single methods. [As documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#test-prefix) decorate a class by one of `patch` decorators act like patch all methods that starts by `patch.TEST_PREFIX`. In your case we use the default value for `patch.TEST_PREFIX` and we can write:

```
@mock.patch('lib.mymodule.ClassC')
@mock.patch('lib.mymodule.ClassB')
@mock.patch('lib.mymodule.ClassA')
def TestHostRecordCreation(self):
    def test_A(self, MockClassA, MockClassB, MockClassC):
        f = MyClass("host", "user", "password")
        self.assertEqual(f, "bogus result")

    def test_B(self, MockClassA, MockClassB, MockClassC):
        f = MyClass("myhost", "myuser", "password")
        self.assertEqual(f, "other bogus result")
```

Finally you can use [`patch.multiple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-multiple) to patch a set of attributes. In that specific synthetic case seams very powerful but in the real word cases its use is very rare:

```
@mock.patch.multiple('lib.mymodule', ClassA=mock.DEFAULT, ClassB=mock.DEFAULT, ClassC=mock.DEFAULT)
def TestHostRecordCreation(self):
    def test_A(self, MockClassA, MockClassB, MockClassC):
        f = MyClass("host", "user", "password")
        self.assertEqual(f, "bogus result")

    def test_B(self, MockClassA, MockClassB, MockClassC):
        f = MyClass("myhost", "myuser", "password")
        self.assertEqual(f, "other bogus result")
```

Consider to use `setUp()` and `tearDown()` if you need to create objects useful for a lot of tests (every test unit framework have something like this). You can either use `setUp()` and `tearDown()` to start and stop patches context but my taste is that decorators and `with` context are more readable.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.  I'm actually using Mamba, which I neglected to mention in my original post (not unittest).  Is there a way to apply this to Mamba, or in your opinion is it worth switching over to unittest instead?

Comment: @blindsnowmobile Of course. In [mentioned documentation] (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#test-prefix) is clear that your class can be of every type (not just a `unittest.TestCase`). The decorator will just apply decorators to all function where the name starts by  `patch.TEST_PREFIX` value; default value is `test` but you can change it as you like. I'll update my answer to remove `unittest` references and make it more general.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to do this with mamba which seems to complicate matters because I can't decorate the "with" context managers.  Since there are no functions to decorate, I tried to look at the patch.start() / patch.stop() methods in before.each as mgilson referenced above. My tests are starting to look rather clunky though, so I think I'm going to be switching over to unittest next time.  Your solution looks more clean.  Marking this as the solution.